# Как правильно записать числительное в предложении

Tags: числительные, количественно-именное-сочетание

Город с 857500 жителями

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше всего так и оставить. Потому что прописью это чисто будет выглядеть слишком громоздко и совершенно нечитаемо.

Answer (score 1):

С восемьюстами пятьюдесятью семью тысячами пятьюстами.

Comment: Почему не "с восемьсот пятьдесят семью тысячами пятьюстами жителями"? Мне действительно не совсем понятно. Существует ли правило на этот счет?

Comment: Просто, из-за соображений эстетики. Правила не существует, но числительное будет слишком громоздким и неудобочитаемым.

Comment: Уважаемые  Fisher  и   Fuchoin Kazuki ! Правила о склонении количественных составных числительных существует, и звучит оно так: склоняется каждый корень и каждое слово. А в составных порядковых  склоняется только последнее слово. Так что   Angry Bird  права, вариант верный. Молодец, птичка!

Answer (score 0):

с восьми ста пятидесяти семи тысяч пяти ста жителями